# Set Spinner focus to the Spinner itself after a user selection

Tags: android, android-spinner

When I turn TalkBack on, once a selection is made in my Spinner, the focus immediately goes back to the top of the screen (toolbar). I would like the focus to be on the spinner immediately after the user's selection.

I have tried setting the spinner to be focusable:

```
spinner.setFocusable(true); 
spinner.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

I have checked out the following StackOverflow questions and answers which do not directly address the issue I have:

- [How can I use onItemSelected in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151414/how-can-i-use-onitemselected-in-android)
- [Adding Focus to a spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241698/adding-focus-to-a-spinner#15015204)

I am noticing that the spinner is briefly disabled as the selection is set. I am guessing this is why the focus gets delegated to a different view. How can I circumvent this disabling or work around it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by performing the following (hopefully this helps someone else with the same issue):

```
    private boolean isUserSelection; // to detect user selection

    spinner.setChangeListener(this);
    spinner.setFocusable(true);
    spinner.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    if (((AccessibilityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE)).isEnabled())
    {
        spinner.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
            {
                if (hasFocus && !isUserSelection)
                    v.performClick(); //bypasses the caret inside the spinner so user doesn't have to tap twice to open the drop down
                else if (!hasFocus && isUserSelection)
                    v.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    }
```

In the itemSelectedListener for the spinner, use this code:

```
if (isUserSelection && (AccessibilityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE)).isEnabled()))
    durationSpinner.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does the focus go to? Try requesting focus from there like this.

```
newlyFocusedView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            newlyFocusedView.clearFocus();
            spinner.requestFocus();
            spinner.performClick();
        }
    }
});
```

Also try `spinner.setFocusable(true);`