# Android: Spinner doesn't get focus properly

Tags: android

I'm running into the following problem:
Within a `ScrollView` I have a `TableLayout` with lots of `EditTexts`, `Spinners`, `RadioGroups` and so on. When the activity starts, the first EditText gains focus. If I scroll down to a `Spinner` and select an item, it automatically scrolls back to the `EditText` which had the focus.

I already tried to use the following:

```
((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.attributes_status)).setFocusable(true);
((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.attributes_status)).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

`R.id.attributes_status` is the spinner. This solves the automatic scroll problem, but now I have to tap the spinner twice (1. set focus, 2. show item list)!

Does anybody know how to set the focus properly to a `Spinner`? Or how to suppress the automatic scroll problem without changing the `Spinner` behaviour?

Thanks in advance and best regards,

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.  I solved it by making the spinner focusable using [`setFocusableInTouchMode(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFocusableInTouchMode(boolean)), but that leads to other problems.  You can see my solution to them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247055#20821508).

Answer (score 0):

As this solves your problem but i have easiest solution of this problem which solves my problem.
First of all to hide the keyboard you can use this:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Then use this code:

```
spinner.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus)
                YourActivity.this.spinner.performClick();
        }

    });
```